# AM radio spectations - how does it work

Tags: circuit-analysis, rf, modulation, ham-radio

I have captured a RF-AM transmitter circuit on internet. It is clear that the input signal will be pre-amplified and then it will begin to modulate the signal. The question is about how the circuit works that has been taken in circle. What does it do? How does the RLC circuit work there and make an output to antenna? Can you help me to decipher this circuit? What kind of oscillation has been taken?

[image: circuit]

Edit:

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1xj-DMWeip56FE-32ba_vP_0s61M77XUv/view
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YiAplBUuGRE

[Zafer Yildiz - Youtube Channel](https://www.youtube.com/channel/UC8rSmNojy8Dw3dKQ2vCgWdw/videos?view=0&sort=p&shelf_id=0)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is your final amplifier.  It is also your oscillator and modulator.

L1, C3, and C4 form a pi filter.  However, they are also a positive feedback path, sending the emitter signal back to the base and further perturbing it.  That results in the oscillation.  It also offers additional amplification of the input signal, and the nonlinear P-N junction will effect modulation (note that the oscillator signal is rectified inherently by the B-E junction).

The emitter follower configuration delivers enough current to drive the antenna.

Comment: Note that the OP and YouTube link seemingly claim that the given circuit is an AM *transmitter*. (Note the mic input).

Comment: This is clearly correct, but it would be interesting to see a small-signal analysis of the oscillator.  The gain from base to emitter is less than one, so the LC filter Q would be key in making sure the oscillator oscillates.